# Reactjs returns undefined of map when trying to zoom when using google maps

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-maps

I'm building an app where a map, displaying different markers which contains data. 
When I zoom I want to change the amount of markers I'm displaying. However, whenever I zoom the app crashes and I get the following error (see link below):

[errorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oiuxt.png)

Below you can see my code. Please let me know if any additional information should be provided. Thanks in advance.

```
//App.js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { compose, withStateHandlers } from "recompose"
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow
} from "react-google-maps"
import Shell from './components/Shell/Shell';
import Features from './components/Features/Features';
import {getFilteredData} from './datamanagement'
import './App.css';


export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      points:  []
    }
  }


  updateMarkers = (zoomLevel) => {
    console.log("HERE: "+zoomLevel)
    this.setState({points:getFilteredData(zoomLevel)})
    console.log(this.state.points)

  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
      <Shell />
      <Features
      points={this.state.points}
      updateMarkers={this.updateMarkers.bind(this)}
      />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

```
//Feature.js

import React, { Component } from "react"
import { compose, withStateHandlers } from "recompose"
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow
} from "react-google-maps"
import Map from './Map/Map';
import Mymarker from './Map/Mymarker';
import SidePanel from './Map/SidePanel/SidePanel';
import App from '../../App';
import {getFilteredData} from '../../datamanagement'

const dumbValues = {
  gps_lat: 7,
  gps_lng: 7,
  humidity_pcnt: 7,
  no2_ppm: 7,
  no_ppm: 7,
  noise_dba: 7,
  o3_ppm: 7,
  pm1_ugm3: 7,
  pm2_5_ugm3: 7,
  pm10_ugm3: 7,
  pressure_hpa: 7,
  temperature_c: 7,
  timestamp: "2007-07-07T07:07:07.007Z",
  __v: 7,
  _id: "7"
}

export default class Features extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.map = React.createRef()

    this.state = {
      points: this.props.points,
      panelValues: dumbValues,
      panelBool: false
    }
  }

  handleUpdatePanel = (values) => {
    if(values._id === this.state.panelValues._id){
      this.setState({panelValues:dumbValues})
      this.setState({panelBool:false})
    } else { //klickade på nån annan
      this.setState({panelValues:values})
      this.setState({panelBool:true})
    }
  }

  handlePanelX = () => {
    this.setState({panelValues:dumbValues})
    this.setState({panelBool:false})
  }

  zoomEvent = () => {
    this.updateMarkers(this.map.current.getZoom())
  }

  updateMarkers = (zoomLevel) => {
    console.log("HERE: "+zoomLevel)
    this.props.updateMarkers({points:getFilteredData(zoomLevel)});
    console.log(this.state.points)
  }

render() {
  return (
    <div className="map">
      <main style= {{marginTop: '59px'}}>
        <Map
          reference={this.map}
          markers={this.props.points}
          zoomHandler={this.zoomEvent}
          googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBa8ciqxkSl8ohhsm1HjPcwjOflZE_yWJs&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
          loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
          containerElement={ <div style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}/>}
          mapElement={ <div style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 59, right: 0, bottom: 55, left: 0}} /> }
          panelFunc={this.handleUpdatePanel}
          />
      </main>
        {this.state.panelBool && <SidePanel values={this.state.panelValues} panelX={this.handlePanelX}/>}
    </div>
  );
};
}
```

---

```
//Map.js

import React from 'react';
import { compose, withStateHandlers } from "recompose"
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow
} from "react-google-maps"
import Mymarker from './Mymarker';

const Map = compose(withScriptjs, withGoogleMap)
(props => {

  return (
    <GoogleMap defaultZoom={11}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: 57.7088700, lng: 11.974560 }}
    onZoomChanged={props.zoomHandler}
    ref={props.reference}
    >
      {props.markers.map(marker => {

        return (
          <Mymarker
            key={marker._id}
            values = {marker}
            updatePanel = {props.panelFunc}
          />
        )
      })}

    </GoogleMap>
  )
})



export default Map;
```

---

This is the data that is returned after assigning the value to the points and console logging this.state.points:

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvZ5n.png)

Comment: What does `getFilteredData` do?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @doniyor2109. It filters the data depending on zoom level. If we are more zoomed in, additional markers will be shown to show the data more clearly. If we are more zoomed out, it will show maybe one or two markers which summarizes the data of that area. Points is an array with data-points which we assign in the updateMarkers method.